# Я пишу бота в aiogram на python, срочно нужна помощь!

Tags: python, aiogram

Я пишу бота в aiogram на python, но у я не знаю как сделать подписку на него.Т.е. я хочу, если человек купил подписку то он мог без ограничений отправлять команды например - /start , а человек без подписки у него был cooldown на отправку сообщений например 50 секунд.Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в таблицу юзеров поле subscription, по дефолту ставится false. Написать фильтр для проверки подписки. При получении подписки значение в поле менять на True